# How to install openssl 1.1.0 pkcs11 engine?

Tags: openssl, raspbian

I am trying to install the pkcs11 engine plugin for Openssl 1.1.0e on Raspbian Stretch. The usual package libengine-pkcs11-openssl install an engine for an earlier version of Openssl. Unsurprisingly it yields an error message about incompatible versions.

It seems it expects a library at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/engines-1.1/pkcs11.so. But I can't find any Raspbian package containing such a file.

Can somebody tell me what package(s) I need to install for this ? And how it translates to the Openssl config ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to rebuild the engine package, but chances are big it does not work with openssl 1.1